# Does image rotation causes loss of pixels?(Core Graphics)

Tags: ios, image-processing, core-graphics, image-rotation

I'm trying to implement image rotation in my code and running a couple of tests. Since I don't know much about the math of how rotation is performed, I just followed some instructions that I'd found on the internet and implemented my code.

I found out that a whole row or column of 1-pixel around the edge is lost everytime I rotate the image. (more than M_PI degree at a time)

This is not obvious when I host the image as a UIImage object, but you can see it when you save the UIImage as a file.

Here's my test code link:
https://github.com/asldkfjwoierjlk/UIImageRotationTest/tree/master

I don't understand that this loss happens. Did I miss something? Or is it something mathematically inevitable?

Here's the rotation method that I implemented if you are interested.

```
- (UIImage*)rotateImg:(UIImage*)srcImg
{
    UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, srcImg.size.width, srcImg.size.height)];
CGFloat rotationInDegree = ROTATION_DEGREE;

CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationInDegree);
rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;


// set opaque option to NO to leave the alpha channel intact.
// Otherwise, there's no point of saving to either png or jpg.
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rotatedSize, NO, 1.0);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, rotatedSize.width / 2.0f, rotatedSize.height / 2.0f);
CGContextRotateCTM(context, rotationInDegree);
[srcImg drawInRect:CGRectMake(-srcImg.size.width / 2.0f, -srcImg.size.height / 2.0f, srcImg.size.width, srcImg.size.height)];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can handle the UIImageView as a View. This code works perfectly for me!

```
 CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
NSNumber *currentAngle = [rotatedViewBox.layer.presentationLayer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
rotationAnimation.fromValue = currentAngle;
rotationAnimation.toValue = @(50*M_PI);
rotationAnimation.duration = 50.0f;             // this might be too fast
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;     // HUGE_VALF is defined in math.h so import it
[rotatedViewBox.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimationleft"];
```

Happy coding!